# Vanilla Minecraft Commands - How do I count the amount of players in an objective?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I am making a Bow Spleef minigame in Minecraft and cannot figure out how to determine a winner when one player is left. What I need is an execute-command that can detect if only one player is left in the Lives objective, then run a command accordingly, similar to this:

```
/execute if score [player_amount] matches 1 run [The Win Sequence]
```

[image: Image of scoreboard here (Except there would be two or more players)]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/365931/185203

Answer (score 0):

If your scoreboard objectives has a fake player (like livesLeft), you can use

```
/execute if score (FAKE-PLAYER) matches 1 run [Command that you want to run]
```

I hope this helped!